# gcc: Thread-local variable compiled as BSS

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, nm

I am new to and testing the *thread-local storage* (TLS) class with `gcc` (version 4.8.2) on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer with i686/32 bit architecture.

In trying to find out whether the `__thread` keyword has the desired effect, I compile this minimalistic test program with `gcc test.c` (no errors or warnings):

```
#include <stdio.h>

__thread int i;

int main() {
  i = 7;
  printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

and use the tool `nm` to check the storage class of the symbol `i` in the object code:

```
nm a.out | grep ' i'
```

The result is

```
00000000 B i
```

which means that `i` is treated as a common global uninitialized variable (stored in the BSS section). According to `man nm`, thread local storage variables are denoted by the letter `L`, not `B`.

What's wrong here?

Is this an `nm` problem or a real problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no problem, it's just the way `nm(1)` writes output.

`nm(1)`'s default output format (and information) is different among platforms (for example the manpage for `nm(1)` in my Linux desktop doesn't even mention `L` for thread-local storage).

However, if you enable SysV output format with `-fs`, you get a more verbose output:

```
$ nm -fs a.out
Symbols from a.out:

Name                  Value           Class        Type         Size             Line  Section

...

i                   |0000000000000000|   B  |               TLS|0000000000000004|     |.tbss
...
```

As you can see, using this output format `i` is identified as being thread local under the column `Type`, and it lives in `.tbss`.

If the manpage for your distribution mentions the `L` flag for thread-local storage and you don't see it in the default output format, I'd say it's a bug in `nm(1)`.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the explanation, indeed I get the same output. As for the man page, I was on a UNIX man page in the web without realizing.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is too minimal. The number of threads won't be known until runtime, so the variable that you see in the executable is the variable that `main` will use. Additional copies of the variable will be allocated when additional threads are created.

Here's a minimal program that demonstrates thread variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

__thread int i;

void *foo( void *args )
{
    i = 8;
    printf( "foo: %d\n", i );
    return NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
    i = 7;
    printf( "main:%d\n", i );

    pthread_t pid;
    if ( pthread_create( &pid, NULL, foo, NULL ) != 0 )
        exit( 1 );

    pthread_join( pid, NULL );
    printf( "main:%d\n", i );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code skeleton, it will actually be helpful for the _real_ program I have in mind to write! But for this question, my problem was more about understanding the `nm` output, so Filipe Gonçalves got the point (he showed me how to check the storage class with `nm -fs`).